# Expected value of playing a game

Tags: probability

A game has probability $\frac13$ of winning. Someone would like to play this game and continue to play until he loses two in a row. What is the expected number of playing the game?

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  consider the early tosses.  Either you get your two consecutive losses quickly, or you restart.

Comment: theres a $\frac 49$ chance of losing twice, given two arbitrary tosses.

Comment: Try and write out equations for $\mathbb{E}[T\vert L=0]$ and $\mathbb{E}[T\vert L=1]$ where $T$ is time and $L$ is current number of losses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a question on the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)(which works just like the law of total probability).

EDIT: I just realized I answered the question for *winning* twice in a row: to apply it to the OP's problem, just change probabilities around.

Let $n =$ the expected length of the game (i.e., the answer you are after).

If the first game is a loss (with probability $2/3$), you have made no progress, and then your expected length is 1+n.

If the first game is a win (with probability $1/3$), you have made some progress: with another win (probability $1/3$), your expected length is 1+1; but with another loss (probability $2/3$), your expected length is $1+(1+n)$ since you are now in the previous case.

So
$$
n=(2/3)(1+n) + (1/3)[(1/3)2 + (2/3)(2+n)]
$$
and you can solve for $n$.

Comment: Does this equation apply for a statement "until he wins 2 times in a row" instead of "until he loses 2 times in a row"? But I got your idea thanks

Comment: Yes @GerryDunda sorry I thought the question was asking about two wins in a row, however just make the obvious changes for the other case.